# how to use "this" in this jquery function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a function where I need to reference "this" inside of window.setTimeout.  Currently it doesn't work. How can I rewrite this so it works? Thanks.

```
 $(function() {
     $('li a').click(function() {
          $(this).parent().css('background-position','left top');
          window.setTimeout("$(this).css('font-size','40px');",1000);
     });
 });
```

Comment: Johnny - Remember to "Accept" an answer by clicking the checkmark next to that answer. Both you and the person who answered get reputation points for it. :o)

Answer (score 4):

As you saw, `this` has a different meaning inside a `setTimeout()`.

One solution is to store the correct value of `this` in a variable, and reference it in the anonymous function that you pass in.

```
 $(function() {
     $('li a').click(function() {
          $(this).parent().css('background-position','left top');
          var th = this;
          window.setTimeout(function() {
                     $(th).css('font-size','40px');
                },1000);
     });
 });
```

Another option is to use jQuery's `$.proxy()` which retains the value of `this` for you.

```
 $(function() {
     $('li a').click(function() {
          $(this).parent().css('background-position','left top');
          window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
                     $(this).css('font-size','40px');
                }, this)
          ,1000);
     });
 });
```

Otherwise, you could create a closure.

```
 $(function() {
     $('li a').click(function() {
          (function( th ) {
              $(th).parent().css('background-position','left top');
              window.setTimeout(function() {
                         $(th).css('font-size','40px');
                    }
              ,1000);
          })( this );
     });
 });
```

Comment: @Kranu - `$.proxy` takes care of that. Otherwise a closure.

Comment: Oh I never actually new about proxy. +1 to your answer for having multiple methods.

Comment: @Kranu - Thanks. I personally prefer the closure, just feels lighter, but `$.proxy()` certainly does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a closure inside your setTimeout call.

```
 $(function() {
      $('li a').click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.parent().css('background-position','left top');
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $this.css('font-size','40px');
            },1000);
          });
     });
```

Should be much closer.

Comment: The anonymous function is good, but `setTimeout()` still calls the function from a different context, so `this` will have a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

```
     window.setTimeout(function(){$(this).css('font-size','40px')},1000);
```

No quotes. And it needs to be a function.